# see nothing mp3 file when use intent type "audio/*"

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

i want to access to mp3 file in devices

```
 private void checkPermission() {
        PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted() {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("audio/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(List<String> deniedPermissions) {
                Toast.makeText(SetVoiceIntroActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        };
        TedPermission.with(this)
                .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
                .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .check();
    }
```

but i see nothing mp3 file although i have some mp3 file.
[image]

so how can i intent to mp3 file like as some media app.

**thanks so much and have a nice day, everyone!**

Comment: You should learn how to operate that gui. There is more then 'Recent'. Use menu left from it.

Comment: i want to intent to folder contain mp3 file . what should i learn?Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

**please try to this**

```
 try {
        //you can change the path, here path is external directory(e.g. sdcard) /Music/maine.mp3  
        mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Music/maine.mp3");

        mp.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```